# Fragment management with drawer layout

Tags: android

I have an app using the slider drawer layout used in applications such as Youtube. I have it setup such that there is one main activity in the main view which cycles through multiple fragments that attach themselves onto that activity. So there are 3 main fragments in the navigation drawer that the user can switch to. Then within each of those three main fragments are more fragments that the user can go to by clicking a button in the main fragment. I am wondering what is the best way to manage all these fragments while preserving a backstack and minimizing the need to reload all of them if the user revists a fragment.

Ex flow:

```
Main             Subfragment
1. Contacts   -> contact details when a contact is clicked
2. ClientList -> client details when a client is selected
3. InfoPage   -> info about each developer
```

Comment: Don't have drawer access for the subfragments (which I call "detail fragments"). Simply open up a new activity to show the subfragment but is otherwise empty.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like hiding/showing the main fragments and attaching/detaching the subfragments. THis is because i switch between the main fragments a lot and it will not have to go through the whole fragment lifecycle everytime the user selects a main frag from the drawer. The trouble is i cant distinguish between  where the user is coming from (main or sub) when i go to switch/hide the fragments

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the entire behavior you want. You could, I guess, that when the user selects a drawer fragment(one of the initial ones) you check the  current fragment and see if there are any nested fragments. If there are any pop them and then detach and reattach the initial fragment. This should work especially if you don't want a back stack between the selection of the initial drawer fragments.

Comment: How do i check and then pop all the nested fragments? fm.popBackStackImmediate(null, fm.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); This does not work

Comment: Did you test to see if you do have something in the backstack? Also, you'd probably want to use the `getChildFragmentManager()` of that fragment as you're dealing with nested fragments.

Answer (score 3):

After reading your question, I would suggest you that in `DrawerLayout`, you can create your main list containing selection of `Contacts`, `ClientList`, and `InfoPage`. By selection of any, you can display related info in Lets say `DetailFragment`. For example, by selection `Contacts` from `DrawerLayout`, all contacts will be displayed in `DetailFragment`. Now, by clicking of any contact from `DetailFragment` it will open / replace current `DetailFragment` and show contact details in another `Fragment`.

In recent project, I followed the recommended way. I am putting demo link here : [NestedFragment](https://github.com/Abhan/Fragments)

I hope this can help you out.

*UPDATE*

Kindly add `ActionBarSherlock` Library as a reference project to this demo.

Thanks.